# MySQL different from

Tags: mysql

How can I do this

```
select * from theuser where userid=1233 and active != 1
```

in a correct MySQL syntax?

`active` can be `NULL`, `0` or `1` and what I need is `active` equal to `NULL` or `0`, never equal to `1`.

Comment: Give it a try and see what happens.  If you don't understand any errors, google them.  If you can't figure it out, let us know.

Comment: @user: You can search SO about `NULL`s and `ternary logic`. Also read this Question/answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465235/in-sql-server-why-is-it-that-null-does-not-equal-empty-string-and-doesnt-not-eq/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select * from theuser where userid=1233 and (active is null or active != 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
  FROM theuser
 WHERE userid = 1233
   AND (active IS NULL OR active != 1)
```

Comment: His query returns only records that have active field equals 0. He can't get rows where active is null if he doesn't explicit it.

Comment: I see. Just checked it. (NULL != 1) evaluates to NULL (instead of TRUE), hence the row will not be selected. Thanks for the correction. Should I edit my answer accordingly?